# Libgdx stop sounds that are currently being played and play a new one

Tags: java, android, audio, libgdx

Am facing this problem in Libgdx (developing for Android) that the sounds are not played sometimes. As far as I realized this is when an old sound has not finished playing. Is there a way to track the sounds currently being played and stop them to play the new sound. I have a looping music running in the background too but that is not causing it as removing it also gives the same sound mismatch. Am loading sounds via AssetManager. Hope you guys can help, thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine whether sound is currently played, well you shouldn't. Of course you can do this by storing length and time when it was played, but `Sound` is created as **fire and forget**.

You can use `Music` and the just use `isPlaying()` method.

Method `play()` returns the id of new sound instance. You can store ids in array and then use `stop(id)` to stop sounds you want or just use `stop()` to stop all instances of that sound.

I would also recommend to check file sizes as from libGDX github wiki:

> note: On Android, a Sound instance can not be over 1mb in size. If you
>   have a bigger file, use Music

Comment: was i right on the argument that the sounds are not playing because old sounds are still playing?

Comment: 'play()' should always create new instance, so it shouldn't do anything with old one, but it is possible that there is a limit for it.

Comment: I have got it solved by loading sounds without the assetmanager

Comment: This is not a good answer. Sounds are not as simple as 'fire and forget' because they can be looped. Also music can only have one instance whereas sound can have multiple IDs. If you want looping sounds then you need to know if they are playing or not.